# How do I add a column to a Pandas dataframe based on other rows and columns in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I've tried a lot of different methods, but I can't seem to find the right way to do this. I want to create a new column based on the `time` and `id` of the df. However, `ids` appear multiple times. Here's my dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [1,2,3, 1, 2 ,3], 
                      'id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                      'num': [10,11,12, 20, 21, 22]}
                  )`

and its output:

`id num time
A   10  1
A   11  2
A   12  3
B   20  1
B   21  2
B   22  3`

What I want is that for the new columns value to be the `num` value for `time==1` for each unique `id`. Here's what I would like the output to be:

`id  num time y
A   10  1   10
A   11  2   10
A   12  3   10
B   20  1   20
B   21  2   20
B   22  3   20`

One attempt I've made is to make a reference table made like this:

`df['y'] = np.where(df['time']==1, df['num'], None)`

`ref = df[['id','y']]`

`ref = ref.dropna()`

But I still don't know where to go from here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can create a new dataframe having only first entries of new ID, copying num to new column y and merging this with original dataframe:

```
newdf = df.drop_duplicates('id')
newdf['y'] = newdf['num']
newdf = df.merge(newdf, how='outer')
```

However, it will put NaN for non-first id rows:

```
print(newdf)
  id  num  time     y
0  A   10     1  10.0
1  A   11     2   NaN
2  A   12     3   NaN
3  B   20     1  20.0
4  B   21     2   NaN
5  B   22     3   NaN
```

One can change these NaN to previous values by following simple loop:

```
tempval = 0   # a variable to store value temporarily
newy=[]
for x in newdf['y']: 
    if not pd.isnull(x): tempval = x
    newy.append(tempval)
newdf['y'] = newy
```

The desired dataframe is obtained:

```
print(newdf)
  id  num  time     y
0  A   10     1  10.0
1  A   11     2  10.0
2  A   12     3  10.0
3  B   20     1  20.0
4  B   21     2  20.0
5  B   22     3  20.0
```

Actually, this question belongs to https://stackoverflow.com/